# How do I add text to navbar in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display the username of the logged in user in my application in Bootstrap 4 navbar. However, it's displayed out of vertical alignment with other elements.

Here's the example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Foo</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span>email@example.com</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

The resulted E-Mail address is displayed `top-right`, however I want it to be displayed `middle-right`.

Comment: remove `pull-xs-right`

Answer (score 3):

Add the class `.nav-link` to the span and then style the color of it accordingly like so:

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/kgqfdnq4/)

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav span.nav-link,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav span.nav-link:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav span.nav-link:focus{
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

It should look like the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Foo</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="nav-link">email@example.com</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Or you can keep your markup and style the span youself whichever you like

```
.navbar-nav span {
    display: block;
    padding-top: .425rem;
    padding-bottom: .425rem;
}
```

Comment: That's to hackish to my taste, but thanks nevertheless. It looks like Bootstrap 4 is way to unfinished, will have to revert to version 3 for now.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a less hackish way at the bottom - bootstrap 4 was supposed to have an emphisis on having a smaller footprint so I doubt they are going to change a lot about it right now the alpha is more just to find bugs but you can style the span directly instead of overriding the styles if that seems less hackish

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the class `pull-xs-right` so :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <span>email@example.com</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Should be :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <span>email@example.com</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or use one `ul` tag like :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Foo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span>email@example.com</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not helping to solve the vertical alignment issue and it makes the text displayed on the left side, and I want it to be floated right.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, wrong description. The text should be in the VERTICAL middle of the navigation bar, now it's vertically aligned to the top border.

Answer (score 0):

Try navbar-text to li like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Foo</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class=" nav-item navbar-text">
            <span>email@example.com</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

see example [here](http://www.bootply.com/xW4Lm6sTGW)

Comment: Sadly, there is no `.navbar-text` class in Bootstrap 4.